# WPF - databinding to a property of same control

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a control (let's say a textbox) and I want bind the value of one property (let's say tooltip) to value of another property in same control(let's say text).

i want something like belowing but I dont know how can I bind the tooltip to text of same control :

```
<textBox text="abc" tooltip={Binding ???} />
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use RelativeSource:

```
<TextBox Text="abc" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Text}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern you can expose a property on the ViewModel and then bind both to the same property:

```
<textBox text="{Binding Text}" tooltip="{Binding Text}" />
```

And in the ViewModel:

```
public string Text { get return "abc"; }
```

This allows you to unit test that the value presented is correct.

Comment: though a bit over the hedge from what he was asking,
i am a MVVM Fan :)